# How do I input the motions for Ibuki's Ultra 1?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

i'm learning ibuki on Street fighter IV:AE and a book said that I needed to do the trails, so I did, but i'm stuck on level 5, I need to do a Yoroitoshi the commands are:
[image][image]
[image]
[image]

But it doesn't seem to work, I get the grap and then blue lazer's, and then I do a punch tree times, what am i doing wrong, can anybody help?

Thanks!

> Images from [this website.](http://thesaltminedotcom.wordpress.com/fighters/44-2/sfxt-characters/ibuki/)

Comment: I thought the HCB was 2x for a Yoroitoshi?

Comment: uhm, can you explain that? its the first time i'm playing street fighter, so I don't now any of the abreviations.

Comment: HCB stands for Half Circle Back, and is the first thing you've already got in the input. You have to do the directional part of the command twice for a Yoroitoshi, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three punches doesn't mean one punch three times. You must press the three punch buttons at the same time. So, the correct command for the Yoroitoshi is [image: HCB] [image: HCB] [image: 3Punches] . That means two half circles clockwise and three punch buttons (or the "All punches" shortcut). You also must do it in close range to the opponent.

[This video](http://youtu.be/O-mcjb9lke4?t=24s) shows Yoroitoshi being executed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, but I do what there stands but I get a raida, this is what I do: http://i.imgur.com/kFkji.jpg

Comment: You have used light punch 3 times. You must use the three punches (light, medium and heavy) at the same time. On the XBox 360, default configuration, this means X+Y+LB, while on the PS3, Square + Triangle + L1. There's the shortcut button, RB on the XBox 360, R1 on the PS3.

Comment: To clarify, also, referring to half-circle back motions as "clockwise" is true if you're standing to the left of your opponent (facing right), but as with all directional commands, it needs to be reversed if you're facing the other way.